# Joomla 2.5 not limit one vote per IP address

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, limit, voting

Joomla 2.5 by default limits the number of how many votes a user can do. This is limited by IP address.

Is there any simple way to allow multiple votes per IP Address?

I am using the CORE Voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Joomla! 2.5 only stores the last voter's IP address per item.

If another vote comes from a different IP address, the user with the original IP address can vote again.

This behavior is defined in `/components/com_content/models/article.php`, circa line 308.

```php
if ($userIP != ($rating->lastip))
{
    $db->setQuery(
            'UPDATE #__content_rating' .
            ' SET rating_count = rating_count + 1, rating_sum = rating_sum + '.(int) $rate.', lastip = '.$db->Quote($userIP) .
            ' WHERE content_id = '.(int) $pk
    );
    if (!$db->query()) {
            $this->setError($db->getErrorMsg());
            return false;
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Changing it involves core file hacking.

One thing that you can do make the test in the `if` clause always return `true`, so one possibility is to comment first line and replace it with

```php
if (true)//$userIP != ($rating->lastip))
{
    $db->setQuery(
            'UPDATE #__content_rating' .
            ' SET rating_count = rating_count + 1, rating_sum = rating_sum + '.(int) $rate.', lastip = '.$db->Quote($userIP) .
            ' WHERE content_id = '.(int) $pk
    );
    if (!$db->query()) {
            $this->setError($db->getErrorMsg());
            return false;
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

I don't find the original core solution that great, and it is not customizable, either.

Comment: Great thanks to you I found a way. Your way on a regular Joomla, not in CCK's that override com_content, but thanks :)